# ng-submit refreshes the page instead of submit

Tags: angularjs, jersey

Hi i have an angular web form which takes input from the user and inserts into the database.I am using jersey-jackson rest web services and hibernate.But when i try to submit the form,the previous page which had the hyperlink to the current page is refreshed and the current page is reloaded again(Loading of previous page is seen in the network log).The url specified in the http request is not even invoked.Following is my code

```html
<div id="main">
  <h1>Create Leave</h1>
    <form class="form-horizontal" ng-controller="MyAddController" >
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="employeeName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Employee Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" id="num" class="form-control" ng-model="num" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"></div>

        </div>
        
           <div class="form-group">
            <label for="leaveType" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Leave Type</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <select id="leaveType" class="form-control" ng-model="leaveType">
                    <option value="">Hospital</option>
                    <option value="female">leave type 2</option>
                     <option value="female">leave type 3</option>
                      <option value="female">leave type 4</option>
                       <option value="female">leave type 5</option>
                        <option value="female">leave type 6</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7"></div>
        </div>
       
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="leaveStartDate" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Leave Start Date</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="date" id="startDates" class="form-control" ng-model="startDate" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7"></div>
        </div>
       
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="leaveEndDate" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Leave End Date</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="date" id="endDate" class="form-control" ng-model="endDate" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7"></div>
        </div>
        
     
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <span><b>Is Half Day leave</b></span>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label><input value="Yes" type="radio" name="halfDay" ng-model="isHalfDay" />Yes</label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label><input value="No" type="radio" name="halfDay" ng-model="isHalfDay" />No</label>
                </div>
            </div>
          
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Save" ng-click='add();' class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-3" /> 
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" ng-click="resetForm()" class="btn" /> <br/>
  
   </form>
   
  <script>
 function MyAddController($scope, $http) {
  $scope.add = function() {
   $http.get("webapi/blog/create", {
    params : {
     
     signum : $scope.num,
     leaveType : $scope.leaveType,
     startDate : $scope.startDate,
     endDate : $scope.endDate,
     isHalfDay : $scope.isHalfDay
    }
   }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    if (data) {
     $scope.data = data;
     alert("success")
    }
   }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    alert("error");
   })
  }

 }
</script>
```

and the bean class

```html
package com.king.entity;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class LeaveDetails {
 
 @Id
 private String num;
 public String getnum() {
  return num;
 }
 public void setnum(String num) {
  this.num = num;
 }
 public String getLeaveType() {
  return leaveType;
 }
 public void setLeaveType(String leaveType) {
  this.leaveType = leaveType;
 }
 public Date getStartdate() {
  return startdate;
 }
 public void setStartdate(Date startdate) {
  this.startdate = startdate;
 }
 public Date getEndDate() {
  return endDate;
 }
 public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
  this.endDate = endDate;
 }
 public String getIsHalfDay() {
  return isHalfDay;
 }
 public void setIsHalfDay(String isHalfDay) {
  this.isHalfDay = isHalfDay;
 }
 private String leaveType;
 private Date startdate;
 private Date endDate;
 private String isHalfDay;
 
 
 

}
```

DAO

```html
package com.king.dao;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import com.king.entity.Blog;
import com.king.entity.LeaveDetails;
import com.king.test.HibernateTest;

public class AddLeaveDao {
 
 public void addDetails(LeaveDetails data) {
  Session session = HibernateTest.getSession();
  Transaction ts = session.beginTransaction();
  session.saveOrUpdate(data);
  session.flush();
  ts.commit();
  session.close();
 }
```

and the WS

```html
package com.king.webapi;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.BeanParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;

import com.king.dao.AddLeaveDao;
import com.king.dao.BlogDao;
import com.king.dao.LeaveDao;
import com.king.entity.Blog;
import com.king.entity.LeaveBalance;
//import com.king.entity.Love;
import com.king.entity.LeaveDetails;

@Path("/blog")
public class BlogWS {

 @GET
 @Path("list")
 @Produces({ "application/json" })
 public List<LeaveBalance> list() {
  List l= new LeaveDao().getAllLeaves();
  Iterator i=l.iterator();
  while(i.hasNext())
  {
   LeaveBalance m=(LeaveBalance)i.next();
   System.out.println(m.getLeaveBalance());
  }
  
  return l;
 }

 @GET
 @Path("create")
 @Produces({ "application/json" })
 public String create(@BeanParam LeaveDetails ld) {
  System.out.println("Entered here");
  new AddLeaveDao().addDetails(ld);
  System.out.println("Returned  here");
  return "{}";
 }

 @GET
 @Path("findById")
 @Produces({ "application/json" })
 public Blog findById(@QueryParam("id") String id) {
  return new BlogDao().findBlogById(id);
 }

 @GET
 @Path("update")
 @Produces({ "application/json" })
 public String update(@BeanParam Blog blog) {
  new BlogDao().updateBlog(blog);
  return "{}";
 }
}
```

edit:actual js i am using

```html
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.calendar','ui.router']);
app.controller('myNgController', ['$scope', '$http', 'uiCalendarConfig', function ($scope, $http, uiCalendarConfig) {
    
    $scope.SelectedEvent = null;
    var isFirstTime = true;
 
    $scope.events = [];
    $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
    $scope.events.push({
        title: "Leave",
        description: "jahsojoaisjjoijaso",
        start: new Date("2017-05-03"),
        end: new Date("2017-05-03"),
        allDay : false,
        stick: false
    });
 
 
    /*//Load events from server
    $http.get('/home/getevents', {
        cache: true,
        params: {}
    }).then(function (data) {
        $scope.events.slice(0, $scope.events.length);
        angular.forEach(data.data, function (value) {
         
        });
    });*/
 
    //configure calendar
    $scope.uiConfig = {
        calendar: {
            height: 450,
            editable: false,
            displayEventTime: false,
            header: {
                left: 'month basicWeek basicDay agendaWeek agendaDay',
                center: 'title',
                right:'today prev,next'
            },
            eventClick: function (event) {
                $scope.SelectedEvent = event;
            },
            eventAfterAllRender: function () {
                if ($scope.events.length > 0 && isFirstTime) {
                    //Focus first event
                    uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', $scope.events[0].start);
                    isFirstTime = false;
                }
            }
        }
    };
 
}]);

app.controller("MyDbController",function ($scope, $http) {
 //$scope.data = [{title: 'welcome hello'},{title: 'great testing'}];

 $http.get("webapi/blog/list", {}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  $scope.data = data;
 }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  alert("error");
 })
});
app.controller("MyAddController",function ($scope, $http) {
 $scope.add = function() {
 $http.get("webapi/blog/create", {
  params : {
   signum : $scope.num,
   leaveType : $scope.leaveType,
   startDate : $scope.startDate,
   endDate : $scope.endDate,
   isHalfDay : $scope.isHalfDay
   
  }
 }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  if (data) {
   $scope.data = data;
   alert("success");
  }
 }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  alert("error");
 })
 }
});

app.config(function($stateProvider){
 $stateProvider
 .state("applyLeave",{
  url:"/applyLeave",
  templateUrl:"html/LeaveApply.html",
  controller:"leaveController",
  controllerAs:"leaveController"
 });
 v.controller("leaveController",function($scope)
   {
  
   })
});
```

When i click on save this is the url pattern shown in the browser. http://localhost:8081/hibernate-jersey-angularjs/?halfDay=No#/applyLeave .I dont understand why .On running http://localhost:8081/hibernate-jersey-angularjs/webapi/blog/create with dummy parameters everything works fine.But on submit i dont think the webservice is not being called.

Please help

Comment: This question belongs on StackOverflow, I hope a mod will move it.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `ng-submit="add()"` on your `<form>` element and remove the `ng-click` from your submit button.

As things stand I don't think that Angular is intercepting the form post and you're just posting form values to the current URL...

Comment: dint work for me

Comment: Try putting your ng-controller in a parent element of the form. I usually develop using the component pattern with Angular so I'm not used to seeing markup like this.